# How do you install Python 3?

Tags: python

Everything I've tried hasn't worked. sudo apt-get install python3.6 gives me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'
```

sudo yum -y install python36 gives me this:

```
There are no enabled repos.
```

And pip install python3.6 gives me this:

```
Collecting python3.6
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3.6 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3.6
```

What can I do to install via command line?

Comment: try sudo apt-get install python3.

Comment: This has very little to do with it being GCP.  It's dependent on what OS you're running on the VM.  But as a first thing to check, have you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I did run sup apt-get update. And when I used sudo apt-get install python 3, I got this: ****Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.5.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.**** but Python --version still says it's 2.7.13

Comment: Looks like python 3.5 is already installed. Just do `python3` in the terminal.

Comment: Our duplicates are mostly asked by people on Macs, but they reflect the same misunderstanding.

Comment: So why does the version show me python 2? I've been trying to install Python 3 so I can install Django, but it still isn't allowing me to do it...